# Log of Queries executed on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

i ran a t-sql query on SQL Server 2005 DB it was suppose to run for 4 days , but when i checked after 4 days i found the machine was abruptly closed. So i want to trace what happened with the query or in other words whats was the status of the query when machine went down 
Is there a mechanism to check this

Answer (score 1):

It may be very difficult to do such a post-mortem.  But while it may not be possible to determine what portion of the long running query was active when the shutdown occured, it is important to try and find the root cause of the problem!

Depending on the way the query is written, SQL will  attempt to roll-back any SQL that wasn't completed (or any uncommitted transaction if transactions were used).  This will happen the first time the server is restarted;  If you have any desire to analyze the SQL transaction log (yuck!) make a copy.

Before getting to the part of the query which may have been running at the time of the shutdown, it may be preferable to look into SQL logs (I mean application logs, with information messages, timestamps and such, not SQL transaction logs for a given database), in search of basic facts, and possibly of an error message, happening some time prior to the shutdown and that could plausibly be the origin of the problem.  Do also check the Windows event logs, as they may indicate abnormal system-wide conditions that could be a cause or consequence of the SQL shutdown.

The SQL transaction log can be "decompiled" and used to understand what was readily updated/inserted/deleted in the database, however this type of info for a 4 days run may be burried quite deep and long and possibly intersped with unrelated queries.  In fact an out of disk space for the SQL log could possibly cause the server to become erratic (I would expect a more elegant handling of such situation, but if somehow the drive in question was also the system drive, bad things could happen...)

Finaly, by analyzing the "4 days long" SQL script it may be possible to infer which parts were completed, thanks to various side-effects of the script.  In nothing else, this review may allow putting back the database in a coherent state if necessary, or to truncate the script to exclude the parts readily completed, in preparation for a new run for completign the work.

Comment: actually i just want to identify was query running at that time or was stopped before the machine went down .
Out of disk cannot be a reason because the partition on which it was running has still 100 GB of space left

Comment: Can you identify any side effect of the query which could prove it completion or near completion ? eventually, this is what will tell you if the long running query completed or not.

Comment: no thats the problem , it was a query generating permutations, so there is no way to identify that all the permutations are generated